# Set selected item or selected index for listbox contains binded items source WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox, converters

I'm newbie on WPF. I didn't success to set selected index\selected value to list box of images items.

My current code is:

On xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="symbolSrc" Grid.Row="1" Width="485" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,-35,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValuePath="photo">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 0 0 0" />
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SymbolComboboxItemsFilter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButLR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButHR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
                            <ListBox.SelectedValue>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SymbolComboboxSelectedItem}">
                                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButLR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName ="RadioButHR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </ListBox.SelectedValue>
</ListBox>
```

On xaml.cs:

```
public class SymbolComboboxItemsFilterConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public class symbolCmbBoxItem
    {
        public string photo { get; set; }
        public string photoName { get; set; }
    }
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<symbolCmbBoxItem> itemsList = new List<symbolCmbBoxItem>();
        string targetDir = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath + "\\..\\..\\..\\INIT\\IC";

        string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if ((bool)values[0])
        {
            foreach (string file in filesArray.Where(s => s.Contains("_LR")))
            {
                itemsList.Add(new symbolCmbBoxItem { photo = file, photoName = "" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string file in filesArray.Where(s => s.Contains("_HR")))
            {
                itemsList.Add(new symbolCmbBoxItem { photo = file, photoName = "" });
            }
        }

        return itemsList;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SymbolComboboxItemsSelectedIndex : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public class symbolCmbBoxItem
    {
        public string photo { get; set; }
        public string photoName { get; set; }
    }
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<symbolCmbBoxItem> itemsList = new List<symbolCmbBoxItem>();
        string targetDir = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath + "\\..\\..\\..\\INIT\\IC";

        string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if ((bool)values[0])
        {
            string item = filesArray.Where(s => s.Contains("_LR")).First();
            return new symbolCmbBoxItem { photo = item, photoName = "" };
        }
        else
        {
            string item = filesArray.Where(s => s.Contains("_HR")).First();
            return new symbolCmbBoxItem { photo = item, photoName = "" };
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I also tried set the selected item by using:

SelectedItem="1"

And it didn't work.

Also tried to using the same multi converter at above and set always the selected item to "1" and it also didn't work.

(In order to set listbox of images I used by below reference:

http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/wpf-combobox-with-image/ )

Any ideas please?

Your help is very appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to correctly bind your listbox using:       SelectedItem="{Binding Path=YourVariable, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

Comment: Please read the online documentation pages of the SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedIndex properties. A comment to your previous question was telling you to set `SelectedIndex` to 1 (which should have been 0 of course). Now you are trying to set `SelectedItem` to 1, which makes no sense at all.